# Sloppy argument to show coordinates are not affected by gravitational waves (GW). Can we make it rigorous?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves

Most textbooks (eg GW's book by Maggiore) say that if a particle is at rest initially ($dx^i/d\tau=0$) in the TT gauge (where $\Gamma^i_{00}=0$), this implies that the acceleration also vanishes *initially*:

$$
\frac{d^2x^i}{d\tau^2}(0) = -\left[\Gamma^i_{00}\left(\frac{dx^0}{d\tau}\right)^2\right]=0.
$$

This is fine and follows from the geodesic equation. The problem is that, after the above, the argument goes as if

$$
\frac{d^2x^i}{d\tau^2}(0) = 0 \implies \frac{d^2x^i}{d\tau^2}(\tau)=0,
$$

for any $\tau$, and they conclude that the coordinate doesn't change when the GW passes by. This doesn't make sense to me at all! This would only make sense in a small neighborhood of $\tau=0$ as can be seen by Taylor expanding the function $x^i(\tau)$ and not for any arbitrary $\tau$.

So my question is: is there any rigorous/mathematical way to prove that the above relation should be valid for any $\tau$ or is this just an approximation? In the latter case, why is it a good approximation of the real world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Propose  a solution to the geodesic equation of the form

$$x^i=const , x^0 = c\tau$$

Then $dx^i/d\tau = 0$ for all $\tau$ so the geodesic equation (space components) reduces to

$$
\frac{d^2x^i}{d\tau^2} +\Gamma^i_{00}\left(\frac{dx^0}{d\tau}\right)^2=0
$$

If then further we have $\Gamma^i_{00} = 0$ then we see our proposed solution is indeed a solution of the geodesic equation.

Likewise for the time component of the geodesic equation.